# Understanding the principle of deferred decisions; how are these events independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I am trying to wrap my head around the proof of the following theorem on the probabilistic verification of matrix multiplication in $\theta(n^2)$ time in Mitzenmacher and Upfal's *Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis*. The proof is used to illustrate a broader technique used in the analysis of randomized algorithms called [the principle of deferred decisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_deferred_decision).

[image]

The proof in the text starts by defining $D = AB - C$. Then $AB\bar{r} = C\bar{r}$ iff $D\bar{r} = 0$. Since $D \neq 0$, $D$ has some nonzero entry $d_{11}$ without loss of generality. For $D\bar{r} = 0$, we must have $\sum_{j=1}^n d_{1j} r_j = 0$. Rearranging gives

$$r_1 = -\frac{\sum_{j=2}^n d_{1j} r_j}{d_{11}}$$

It then follows from the law of total probability that

[image]

I understand that the $\{r_i : i \in [n]\}$ are independent, and thus $r_1$ and $(r_2, ... r_n)$ are independent. But how could the events $r_1 = -\frac{\sum_{j=2}^n d_{1j} r_j}{d_{11}}$ and $(r_2,...,r_n) = (x_2,...,x_n)$ possibly be independent when the value of the right hand side of the former depends clearly on the latter?

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of the summation at all.  Why cannot you say $\Pr(\mathbf{AB}\bar{r}=\mathbf{C}\bar{r})=\Pr\left( r_1 = -\frac{\sum_{j=2}^n d_{1j} r_j}{d_{11}} \right)\le \frac12$ directly?

Comment: @Henry My understanding is that $r_1 = -\frac{\sum_{j = 2}^n d_{1j}r_j}{d_{11}}$ is a necessary condition for $AB\bar{r} = C\bar{r}$, but it is not sufficient.

Comment: OK then $\Pr(\mathbf{AB}\bar{r}=\mathbf{C}\bar{r})\le \Pr\left( r_1 = -\frac{\sum_{j=2}^n d_{1j} r_j}{d_{11}} \right)\le \frac12$

Comment: @Henry This is a good question! I think the authors may have been deliberately verbose to illustrate the law of total probability, which was introduced just prior to the proof of this theorem in the book.